# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'

Tags: angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms, angular2-changedetection

I have kendo date picker and a div, which showing "Required" message in angular4 reactive form.

```
<kendo-datepicker #datePicker=appDateFormat
                          [(value)]="questionControlInfoData.currentValue"
                          [format]="dateFormat"                                         
                          [formatPlaceholder]="{ year: 'yyyy', month: 'mm', day: 'dd' }"
                          [formControlName]="questionControlInfoData.formControlName" [disabled]="questionControlInfoData.disabledControl"
                          [appDateFormatOnly]="dateValidationFormat"> </kendo-datepicker>
 <div> <span *ngIf="!isValid()" [class.star]="!isValid()">This field is required</span> </div>
```

The reactive form is loading the controls dynamically.

The "appDateFormatOnly" is a directive used for date format validation.

I have a method "isValid()", which is returning one boolean value based on some condition.

```
isValid() {

        var dateValue = this.qnaFormGroup.controls[this.questionControlInfoData.formControlName].value;
        var hasDateValue = (dateValue !== undefined && dateValue !== "");

        if (hasDateValue && !this.datePickerDirective.isValid) {

            this.qnaFormGroup.controls[this.questionControlInfoData.formControlName].setErrors({ 'invalidDate': true });
        }


        var isValid = this.qnaFormGroup.controls[this.questionControlInfoData.formControlName].touched ? this.qnaFormGroup.controls[this.questionControlInfoData.formControlName].valid
            : this.qnaFormGroup.controls[this.questionControlInfoData.formControlName].dirty ? this.qnaFormGroup.controls[this.questionControlInfoData.formControlName].valid : true;

        return hasDateValue || isValid;
    }
```

Inside this "isValid()" method I am adding error to the control based on some condition using the "setErrors" angular4 method.

The"isValid()" is called if anything changed in this reactive form.

The issue is:

Sometimes I am getting the error `"ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'."`  while typing the date value in the date picker..

**I have analyzed and found that the issue is with adding error in the form control using "setErrors" method.**

Could you please someone give any solution for this problem.